# XOR combination between the bits of a string

Tags: programming, combinatorics, permutation

Given an integer n, we can construct $2^n$ strings of length n. We can take the first element for each of these strings and create a list. In total 'n' such lists are possible. But now I need to create lists that are the XOR combinations of the n lists created. If n is 3 and abc is the string then I need to calculate a$\oplus$b, a$\oplus$c, c$\oplus$b, a$\oplus$b$\oplus$c. How do I do this for a general n?

Here's the code so far...

`n = 4; s = Tuples[{0, 1}, n]; a = Table[s[[i, j]], {j, 1, n}, {i, 1, 2^n}]`

a gives the first four indices of all the strings. Now I need to calculate all the XOR combinations possible between these four lists.

Comment: does `Mod[Plus@##, 2] & @@@ Subsets[a, {2, n}]` give what you need?

Comment: or (the same thing)  `Mod[Plus@##, 2] & @@@ Subsets[Transpose[s], {2, n}]`?

Comment: or more concisely, `Mod[Plus @@@ Subsets[Transpose[s], {2, n}], 2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
xOrCombinations[n_] := BitXor @@@ Subsets[Transpose @ Tuples[{0, 1}, n], {2, n}]

xOrCombinations[4] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Also

```
xOrCombinations2[n_] := Mod[Plus @@@ Subsets[Transpose@Tuples[{0, 1}, n], {2, n}], 2]

xOrCombinations2[4] == xOrCombinations[4]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```